# jQuery.eCalendar() - use for loop on events

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am trying to display events on the calendar by using for loop. With my current code, only the last one can be displayed on the calendar. Is there anyways I can show all on calendar events by using **only javascript**?

Thanks in advance!

Below is for loop:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]);
}
for (var j in data) {
  title = data[j].title;
  description = data[j].description;
  year = data[j].year;
  month = data[j].month;
  day = data[j].day;
}
```

Below is to display events on the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').eCalendar({
  weekDays: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
  months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
  textArrows: {
    previous: '<',
    next: '>'
  },
  eventTitle: 'Event',
  url: '',
  events: [{
    title: title,
    description: description,
    datetime: new Date("" + year + "," + month + "," + day + "")
  }],
  firstDayOfWeek: 0
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for/in loop to:

```
const events = [];
data.forEach(d=> {
    events.push({
        title: d.title,
        description: d.description,
        datetime: new Date(`${d.year},${d.month},${d.day}`)
    });
});
```

And then pass the event array to your eCalendar:

```
$('#calendar').eCalendar({
    weekDays: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    textArrows: {
        previous: '<',
        next: '>'
    },
    eventTitle: 'Event',
    url: '',
    events: events,
    firstDayOfWeek: 0
});
```

Comment: I got this error on my console. > SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'const'

Comment: Syntax should be correct, I added some sample data to the snippet. Press on Run code snippet to see the output. If you dont find your syntax error, paste your updated code so we can take a look

Comment: I'll hope my update help you out, otherwise let me know, ill be back in about 30minutes. gl ;)

Comment: It was a pleasure, please mark the question as solved to helpout other ppl running into this problem aswell ;)